# JScrollPane add wrong horizontal scroll, when adding JLabel with setMaximumSize

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jscrollpane

**Task**: Add some quantity of JLabel with some text to JPanel with BoxLayout and next add this panel to JScrollPane for scrolling down that text labels.

---

**Problem**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSXuU.png]

I set *text.setMaximumSize(..)*, but JScrollPane don't think so and add horizontal scrollbar. *text.setPreferredSize* limit perfectly, but i can't use it because need calculate height for each label (maybe use font size and getting label auto line breaker) and it's hard for me.

---

Here's code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class NewPanel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel text;

    public NewPanel() {
        int formWidth = 700;
        int formHeight = 700;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            sb.append("Test String ");
        String resStr = "<html>" + sb.toString() + "</html>";

        text = new JLabel();
        text.setText(resStr);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(text);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(
                panel,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
        );

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(formWidth, formHeight));
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();

        //Change max width for label with form resize
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                super.componentResized(e);
                resizePanels();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                super.componentMoved(e);
                resizePanels();
            }
        });

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void resizePanels() {
        int labelSize = frame.getWidth() - 200;
            // - 200 For show that text limited by setMaximumSize

        text.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(labelSize, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            //Integer.MAX_VALUE - for unlimited height (maybe exist better way?)

        //text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(labelSize, 1000));
            //limit perfect and hide horizontal scroll, but don't think that it better way
            //because i need get plane border "back to back" text border,
            //so i must count label height (front height + maybe label auto line break place)
            //that look like hard way
        text.revalidate();
        text.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need to calculate the size of anything, that’s the point of the layout manager, avoid using setMaximum/minimum/preferredSize

Comment: `text.updateUI();` - don't use the updateUI() method. That method is invoked internally on a LAF change. When you add components to a panel you should invoke revalidate() and repaint() on the panel.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so how i can do this? Unfortunatly, I don't find how tune layout manager for my task, maybe you give me example?

Comment: @camickr thank you for advice i replaced method and edited code in post how you said.

Comment: Okay, i find the solution, but not with JLabel, so need just replace JLabel to JTextArea, and in resize:
        textArea.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        textArea.revalidate();
        textArea.repaint();